# Why does the toString method on scala.Function1 and scala.Function2 have parenthesis

Tags: function, scala, tostring, scala-ide, intellij-13

I am implementing a derivation of `(Int) => String)` and overriding the `toString` method like this:

```
object A extends ((Int) => String) {
  override def toString: String = "A"
  def apply(int: Int): String = int.toString
}
```

IDEA IntelliJ indicates the `toString` method is being overriden from `Function1.toString` (as does Scala IDE). And IntelliJ also shows the following warning indicating empty parenthesis must be added to the `toString` method due to the `Function1.toString` declaration including empty parenthesis (Scala IDE does NOT show this warning):

> Empty-paren Scala method overridden as parameterless
>
> The convention is that you include parentheses if the method has side
>   effects. In accordance with Liskov substitution principle, as
>   overriden method is empty-paren, the overriding method must also be
>   declared as a method with side effects. * Refer to Programming in
>   Scala, 5.3 Operators are methods

I then went to the ScalaDoc and checked [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/Function1.scala)), [Function2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2) ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/Function2.scala)) and [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction) ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala)) in the scala package. In the source code for 2.11.2, `Function1` and `Function2` each overrides the `toString` method and includes empty parenthesis (and `PartialFunction` just uses `Function1`'s override). So, given both `Function1` and `Function2` declare a `String` literal for the `toString` method, I don't understand why the parenthesis would have been included in the source code for these two class files.

What obvious thing am I missing which justifies the use of parenthesis on the `toString` method? Or is the IntelliJ warning incorrect? Or if the IntelliJ warning is correct, why isn't the Scala IDE showing the same warning as IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`override def f` overriding `def f()` is assumed to have parens, by the spec.

The IntelliJ message you quote says there is a "convention" that you should include the parens to document that the method is not just an accessor but may have side-effects.

Not everyone agrees with or conforms to that notational "convention."

The convention is especially empty in the case of `toString`, since many `toString` methods are side-effecting, such as iterators initializing state.

I just asked this on the ML recently:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/ahNPTB6-P3M/1pPyptaH6coJ

I answered my own question in the follow-up:

```
http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#overriding
```

> A special rule concerns parameterless methods. ... f is also assumed
>   to have an empty parameter list.

Which means you can leave the parens off the overriding definition.

For example,

```
scala> def f = 42
f: Int

scala> f()
<console>:9: error: Int does not take parameters
              f()
               ^

scala> class X { def f() = 42 }
defined class X

scala> class Y extends X { override def f = 43 }
defined class Y

scala> new Y().f()
res1: Int = 43
```

`Y.f` has an empty param list.

Since `Object.toString()` has an empty param list, so does every override, including overrides of [Any.toString](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#root-classes).

(Java's `toString()` is cited as the reason parens are supplied, in the conversion called "Empty application".)

Comment: Tysvm for answering. I have read your answer three times AND also read the google thread. I still am not able to confidently draw a conclusion. So, is the short answer this? Parenthesis when overriding the toString method are not necessary which means the IntelliJ's warning is incorrect. If so, I will accept your answer if you could please put that (or something in your own words) at the top as a summary (or tl;dr) so future readers can quickly draw the conclusion without having to read deeper. If not, then please help me understand the answer to the three questions in my final paragraph.

Comment: And if the answer is that the parenthesis can be left off, do you know why they weren't they left off scala.Function1 and scala.Function2 (especially since they are assigned a String literal)?

Comment: I used stronger words.